# How to avoid grey screen when I close excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I use an addin that once opened opens other workbooks ( *.xlsm files) with some macros. These workbooks are hidden and contribute their macros only.
When I close excel what I see is that grey screen which indicates there is still a hidden workbook open. 
How to avoid that and make excel close all hidden workbooks automatically like it happens with PERSONAL.xlsb macrobook?

Thanks.

Comment: Either Shift+Click the application X or use the Exit button, which you can add to the Ribbon or QAT.

Comment: How are you closing? Are you closing the workbook or using `Application.Quit`?

Answer (score 1):

You can write the event in Thisworkbook

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.Visible = False

End Sub